# How to display chatterfeed shell in a visualforce page

Tags: apex, chatter, chatter-feed

I have a requirement to assign vf pages to the record type. Now I'm struggling with case detail page because i need to show chatterfeed shell button like standard page layout.

But if I use chatterfeed it's showing directly all updates & user not able to display show/hide button.

Standard view

[image]

In vf page
[image]

How to achieve like in a standard way.I need guidance to setup this model

Answer (score -1):

I hope you started by cloning your original page layout so you didn't lose the specific functionality that you're referring to since it may have been something that was custom.

That said, you have the Chatterfeed drop down button set to show all updates. You'll want to create new filter conditions for just the record type your page is for. You should be able to create another filter that will allow you to do the equivalent of filtering out all updates from any record type to solve your issue.

Comment: Right now I'm not colning my original page layout.because i have multiple criterias are there.Right now it's showing all the updates I'm not able to hide the feed.please let me know how to hide feed in vf page

Answer (score -2):

The chatterexpando and chatterfeedshell visualforce component is not available for us for custom visualforce pages.

Comment: While this may be correct, it's not much of a useful answer. If the only route is custom development it'd be better to show an example of that. I think that's why you've been downvoted by the community.